# Magento upgrade issue

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I badly need your help, I am struglling over this..

> MY Question is ----How can I upgrade my mag from 1.5 to 1.7 while keeping all the
>   products in tact??

Please help me, I have read so many articles over magento forum, SO and google, but nothing could help me...how should I do this?

thanks..

Comment: check if your $this->_getConnection() is really creating a connection object.If there is a connection object then this error will not be displayed.

Comment: This smells like an issue with the cache or possibly a local module with a core override.  Try disabling all non-core modules and anything in app/code/local/Mage